# CSS tables in cakephp

Tags: php, html, cakephp, html-table

I have a situation, I wish to have 3 word in 1 table data.

For example,
one, two, three

I want four to appear below.

For example.

1. One, two, three,
2. four, five, six,
3. seven, eight, nine,
4. and so on..

How do I achieve this using table. Am trying to incorporate this in cakephp. I am using for loop to list the numbers down.

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>  

            <?php foreach ($professionalPassion as $us): ?>


                <td>
        <legend><?php echo $us['PassionsUser']['passion_tag'] ?></legend>

        Type: <?php echo $us['PassionsUser']['type'] ?><br/>                                 
        Description: <?php echo $us['PassionsUser']['description'] ?><br/> 
        <?php echo $this->Html->link(__('Edit', true), array('controller' => 'PassionsUsers', 'action' => 'edit_passion', $us['PassionsUser']['id'])); ?> | 
        <?php echo $this->Html->link(__('Delete', true), array('controller' => 'PassionsUsers', 'action' => 'delete', $us['PassionsUser']['id'])); ?>

    <?php endforeach; ?>
</td>
</tr>

</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a helper function I wrote to do exactly that:

```
function auto_table($cells, $cols, $class = '') {
  $table = '<table' . (empty($class) ? '' : ' class="' . $class . '"') .'><tbody><tr>';

  $current_col = 1;
  foreach ($cells as $cell) {
    // Add the cell
    $table .= "<td class=\"col-$current_col\">$cell</td>";

    if ($current_col % $cols == 0) {
      $table .= '</tr><tr>';
      $current_col = 1;
    }
    else {
      $current_col++;
    }
  }

  // Clear up
  $remaining = $cols - ($current_col == 1 ? 4 : ($current_col - 1));
  for ($i = 0; $i < $remaining; $i++) {
    $table .= '<td class="col-' . $current_col++ . '">&nbsp;</td>';
  }

  $table .= '</tr></tbody></table>';

  return $table;
}
```

`$cells` will contain your array of data, `$cols` the number of columns for the table, and `$class` any class to add to the table.

**UPDATE**

Integrated with your code:

```
$cells = array();
foreach ($professionalPassion as $us) {
  $cell = 'Type: ' . $us['PassionsUser']['type'] . '<br />';
  $cell .= 'Description: ' . $us['PassionsUser']['description'] . '<br />';
  $cell .= $this->Html->link(__('Edit', true), array('controller' => 'PassionsUsers', 'action' => 'edit_passion', $us['PassionsUser']['id']));
  $cell .= ' | ';
  $cell .= $this->Html->link(__('Delete', true), array('controller' => 'PassionsUsers', 'action' => 'delete', $us['PassionsUser']['id']));
  $cells[] = $cell;
}

$html_table = auto_table($cells, 3);
```

Comment: How can I incorporate the helper with my above code I just posted?

Comment: Just build up an array of data in the order that you want it to be displayed as if it was horizontally wrapping. So `array('one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five')` passed as the `$cells` paramater to the function would produce two rows with `one`, `two` and `three` on the first row, and `four` and `five` on the second row, assuming you pass `3` as the `$cols` parameter

Comment: But based on my code, I want my entire for each result to be situation in 'one' and so forth.

Comment: Well build up an array with those values in it then, I can't write your program for you!!

Comment: oh, so I got to put those values in an array, ok I thought the helper will do that. ok thanks

Comment: Yep, I've put a quick example in the answer above that might help

Comment: How do I add CSS style to this $cell?

Answer (score 2):

```
<table>
  <tbody>
     <?php foreach(array_chunk($pp, 3) as $us) : ?>
     <tr>                                      
        <td><?php echo implode(',', $us)?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>    
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I assumed the OP wanted 3 columns, not one column with comma separated values, but now I'm not that sure.

Comment: @Juhana He can `implode('</td><td>', $us)` also if he wanted 3 td.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the HTML helper to create the table, with something like this:

First, divide the contents into cells.

```
$table = array();
$index = 0;
foreach( $pp as $us ) {
    $table[ floor( $index / 3 ) ][ $index % 3 ] = $us;
    $index++;
}
```

Then echo the table using `$html->tableCells()`.

```
echo '<table>';
echo $html->tableCells( $table );
echo '</table>';
```